# On the codomain of a complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I want to denote a complex function that its outputs are real. So I must write:

$$f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$$

However, what happens to those $z$ that make $f(z)$ complex? Are they considered and then I cut off the imaginary output. For instance, let:

$$f(z) = z^2 + x_0, \,\,\, x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$$

If $z=i$, it is fine. But what if $z=1+i$, should I cut off the imaginary part $(2i)$ from the output $2i+x_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$, you are stating that all the values  $f(z)$ are real, for all $z \in \mathbb C$.  So if your function is  $f(z) = z^2 + x_0$ and you write $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$, you have just made 
a mistake.

If not all the values are real, but you "cut off" the imaginary part, you have a different function, namely the real part of your original function.
The original function $f$ does not map $
\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb R$, but $\text{Re} f$ does.

Comment: So, is this a way of writing it? $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}\\ z \mapsto \Re(f(z))$?

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be well-defined, then it is necessary that $f(\mathbb{C}) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

The function that you gave is not well-defined into $\mathbb{R}$ if $x_0 \neq -2i + p(z)$ where $p(z)$ is some real-valued function. So it doesn't make sense to have $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$.

An example of a well-defined function $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the following:

$$g(z) = \begin{cases} 
      z & \text{ if } z \in \mathbb{R} \\
      0 & \text{ if } z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{R}.
   \end{cases}$$

This guarantees that $g(\mathbb{C}) \subset \mathbb{R}$. If you have a function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ but want to make its image restricted to $\mathbb{R}$, then you can, for example, define the following function $h: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$h(z) = \begin{cases} 
      f(z), & \text{ if } f(z) \in \mathbb{R} \\
      0, & \text{ if } f(z) \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R}.
   \end{cases}$$

So in your example with $f(z) = z^2 + x_0$ with $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ we have, $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ iff $z^2 + x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ i.e. iff $z^2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus the function:

$$h(z) = \begin{cases} 
      z^2 + x_0, & \text{ if } z^2 \in \mathbb{R} \\
      0, & \text{ if } z^2 \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R}.
   \end{cases}$$

is well-defined into $\mathbb{R}$. You could, of course, replace $0$ there with a real-valued function or constant.

Answer (score 1):

If you

> "want to denote a complex function (say, $f$) that its outputs are real",

then it is *never* going to happen that

> there are "some $z$ that make $f(z)$ complex<sup>1</sup>".

The function $f(z)=z^2+1$ is *not* such an example because "its outputs" are *not* all real.

<sup>1</sup>
Assume that "complex" means $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, i.e., "non-real", here.